# Mongodb how to get the sum of two columns and save it to another column

Tags: mongodb

Hi my mongodb collection is look likes this

```
{ "created" : ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "total_page_impression_count" : 500, "total_page_story_count" : 7 }
{ "created" : ISODate("2013-01-02T00:00:00Z"), "total_page_impression_count" : 511, "total_page_story_count" : 7 }
{ "created" : ISODate("2013-01-03T00:00:00Z"), "total_page_impression_count" : 513, "total_page_story_count" : 7 }
```

and I want to persist the value of (total_page_impression_count + total_page_story_count) in another column on the same table. Any one know a way to do that. According to the finding what I got to know is it is not possible like SQL. I'll be great full if anyone can help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate all documents and write aggregate field manually. using your language driver or javascript shell. Yes, there's no `update users set full_name = first_name + last_name` kind of commands in mongodb.

Comment: why mongodb lacking that functionality?

Comment: Nobody found the time to implement it, probably. You can suggest this on their jira. Or implement yourself and send a pull-request. It's open-source! :)

Comment: :) Okay Thank you .. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think application logic is an application logic. And saving results of aggregating to perform new level of denormalization at deal with questionable performance gain is layed, 1st of all, on developer choice . So, do 10gen need to implement such functionality at all?

---

googletranslate

Answer (score -1):

mongodb is not RDB.
mongodb has not "join" function.

```
db.yourtable.insert({ "created" : ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "total_page_impression_count" : 500, "total_page_story_count" : 7 })
```

you need to insert 2 times.

```
db.yourtable.insert({ "created" : ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "total_page_impression_count" : 500, "total_page_story_count" : 7 });
db.othertable.insert({"total_page_story_count":507});
```